# Google Sheets: IF statement Arguments Error using dates and sum

Tags: google-sheets

I have looked and looked to find a solution using more than 3 arguments. The formula works for the first 3 statements and then errors out. (#N/A)

I want the spreadsheet based on TODAYS DATE (AB1) to ADD certain cells and then DIVIDE by the number provided in the formula to get a percentage.

```
=IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 11, 30), (C4+D4)/20,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 1), (C4+D4)/40,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 2), (C4+D4)/60,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 3), (C4+D4)/8),
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 4), (C4+D4)/100, 
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 7), (C4:F4)/120,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 8), (C4:F4)/140,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 9), (C4:F4)/160,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 10), (C4:F4)/180,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 11), (C4:F4)/200,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 11, 14), (C4+H4)/220,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 15), (C4+H4)/240,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 16), (C4+H4)/260,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 17), (C4+H4)/280,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 18), (C4+H4)/300,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 4), (C4+J4)/320,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 5), (C4+J4)/340,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 6), (C4+J4)/360,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 7), (C4+J4)/380,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 8), (C4+J4)/400,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 11), (C4+L4)/420,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 12), (C4+L4)/440,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 13), (C4+L4)/460,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 14), (C4+L4)/480,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 15), (C4+L4)/500,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 19), (C4+N4)/520,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 20), (C4+N4)/540,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 21), (C4+N4)/560,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 22), (C4+N4)/580,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 25), (C4+P4)/600,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 26), (C4+P4)/620,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 27), (C4+P4)/640,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 28), (C4+P4)/660,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 1), (C4+R4)/680,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 2), (C4+R4)/700,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 3), (C4+R4)/720,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 4), (C4+R4)/740,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 5), (C4+R4)/760,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 8), (C4+T4)/780,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 9), (C4+T4)/800,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 10), (C4+T4)/820,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 11), (C4+T4)/840,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 12), (C4+T4)/860,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 16), (C4+V4)/880,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 17), (C4+V4)/900,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 18), (C4+V4)/920,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 22), (C4+X4)/940,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 23), (C4+X4)/960,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 24), (C4+X4)/980,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 25), (C4+X4)/1000,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 26), (C4+X4)/1020,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 1), (C4+Z4)/1040,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 2), (C4+Z4)/1060,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 3), (C4+Z4)/1080,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 4), (C4+Z4)/1100,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 5), (C4+Z4)/1120)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

there is extra end bracket after 3rd IF

try:

```
=IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 11, 30), (C4+D4)/20,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 1), (C4+D4)/40,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 2), (C4+D4)/60,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 3), (C4+D4)/8,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 4), (C4+D4)/100, 
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 7), (C4:F4)/120,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 8), (C4:F4)/140,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 9), (C4:F4)/160,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 10), (C4:F4)/180,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 11), (C4:F4)/200,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 11, 14), (C4+H4)/220,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 15), (C4+H4)/240,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 16), (C4+H4)/260,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 17), (C4+H4)/280,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2020, 12, 18), (C4+H4)/300,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 4), (C4+J4)/320,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 5), (C4+J4)/340,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 6), (C4+J4)/360,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 7), (C4+J4)/380,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 8), (C4+J4)/400,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 11), (C4+L4)/420,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 12), (C4+L4)/440,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 13), (C4+L4)/460,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 14), (C4+L4)/480,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 15), (C4+L4)/500,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 19), (C4+N4)/520,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 20), (C4+N4)/540,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 21), (C4+N4)/560,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 22), (C4+N4)/580,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 25), (C4+P4)/600,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 26), (C4+P4)/620,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 27), (C4+P4)/640,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 1, 28), (C4+P4)/660,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 1), (C4+R4)/680,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 2), (C4+R4)/700,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 3), (C4+R4)/720,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 4), (C4+R4)/740,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 5), (C4+R4)/760,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 8), (C4+T4)/780,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 9), (C4+T4)/800,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 10), (C4+T4)/820,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 11), (C4+T4)/840,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 12), (C4+T4)/860,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 16), (C4+V4)/880,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 17), (C4+V4)/900,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 18), (C4+V4)/920,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 22), (C4+X4)/940,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 23), (C4+X4)/960,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 24), (C4+X4)/980,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 25), (C4+X4)/1000,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 2, 26), (C4+X4)/1020,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 1), (C4+Z4)/1040,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 2), (C4+Z4)/1060,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 3), (C4+Z4)/1080,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 4), (C4+Z4)/1100,
 IF(AB1 = DATE(2021, 3, 5), (C4+Z4)/1120))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```